# Is there a way to color replies in the email body on mu4e?

Tags: colors, email, mu4e

I'm on some mailing lists and there is a top-post culture. It's difficult for me to visually delineate the reply from the original content. Is there facility for coloring (perhaps in alternating colors) the nested replies in the email body?

EDIT: It looks like the issue is that the mailing list doesn't insert `>` characters in the replied-to text.